# Вызвать элемент с xml в другом activity

Tags: java, android, xml, adapter

У меня есть TabActivity, которое содержит несколько Tab (FirstTab, SecondTab). У этого TabActivity есть xml, в котором имеется картинка (пока она не видимая). В SecondTab есть xml и адаптер. Как сделать, чтобы при нажатии кнопки в адаптере, принадлежащем SecondTab, картинка в tabActivity.xml становилась видимой?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[TabActivity](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/app/TabActivity.html) was deprecated in API level 13. Использовать не рекомендуется.

Вашу проблему решит к примеру LocalBroadcast

ReceiverActivity.java

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

  ...

  // Register to receive messages.
  // We are registering an observer (mMessageReceiver) to receive Intents
  // with actions named "custom-event-name".
  LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(mMessageReceiver,
      new IntentFilter("custom-event-name"));
}

// Our handler for received Intents. This will be called whenever an Intent
// with an action named "custom-event-name" is broadcasted.
private BroadcastReceiver mMessageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // Get extra data included in the Intent
    String message = intent.getStringExtra("message");
    Log.d("receiver", "Got message: " + message);
  }
};

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
  // Unregister since the activity is about to be closed.
  LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(mMessageReceiver);
  super.onDestroy();
}
```

SenderActivity.java

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

  ...

  // Every time a button is clicked, we want to broadcast a notification.
  findViewById(R.id.button_send).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
      sendMessage();
    }
  });
}

// Send an Intent with an action named "custom-event-name". The Intent sent should 
// be received by the ReceiverActivity.
private void sendMessage() {
  Log.d("sender", "Broadcasting message");
  Intent intent = new Intent("custom-event-name");
  // You can also include some extra data.
  intent.putExtra("message", "This is my message!");
  LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(intent);
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, работает)